# Unity3D text doesn't show up when it build in Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, text, build

It works well on Unity, but it couldn't when it build in Android. Here is my code.

```
1. private string path;// = Application.dataPath + "/Resources/";
2. private string filename = "Magnelli_0.27.txt";
3. private TextAsset asset;
4. private string str;
5. private string[] names;
6. private Vector3 ViewPosition;
7. private double ViewZPosition;
8. 
9. private int length;
10. private double[] arrZ;
11. private double[] arrCV; 
12. 
13. // Use this for initialization
14. void Start () {
15.     Screen.sleepTimeout = SleepTimeout.NeverSleep;
16.     //AssetDatabase.ImportAsset(path);
17.     //LoadTextFile();
18. 
19.     path = Application.dataPath + "/Resources/";
20.     asset = Resources.Load ("Magnelli_0.27")as TextAsset;
21.     str = asset.ToString();
22.     names = str.Split('\n');
23.     length = names.Length;
24. 
25.     Debug.Log ("length: " + length);
26.     //Debug.Log ("str: " + str);
27.     Debug.Log ("names[0]: " + names[0] + "names[1]: " + names[1]);
28.     //Debug.Log (asset.text);   
29. }
30. 
31. // Update is called once per frame
32. void Update () {
33. 
34.     ViewPosition = GameObject.FindWithTag("MainCamera").transform.position;
35.     ViewZPosition = ViewPosition.z;
36. 
37.     StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (path + filename);
38. 
39.     TextReader txtreader = new StringReader (asset.text);
40. 
41.     StringReader streader = new StringReader (asset.text);
42. 
43.     string txt = "";
44. 
45.     arrZ = new double[length];
46.     arrCV = new double[length];
47. 
48.     for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
49. 
50.         txt = streader.ReadLine();
51.         //Debug.Log ("txt: " + txt);
52.         string[] sprite = txt.Split (' ');
53. 
54.         foreach (string b in sprite) {
55.             //Debug.Log ("b: " + b);
56.         }
57. 
58.         
59.         
60.         arrZ[i] = Convert.ToDouble(sprite[0]);
61.         arrCV[i] = Convert.ToDouble(sprite[1]);
62.     }
63.         
64.     // clear memories
65.     reader.Dispose();
66. 
67.     for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
68.         
69.         if ((arrZ[i])*100-0.2 < ViewZPosition & (arrZ[i])*100+0.2 > ViewZPosition)
70.         {
71. 
72.             GetComponent<Text>().text = "redshift z : " + ViewZPosition*0.01 + "\nComoving Volume : " + arrCV[i] + " Gpc³";
73.         }
74.     }
75. 
76.     reader.Close ();
77.     txtreader.Close ();
78. 
79. }
```

and here are screenshots.

[image: Unity']

but these text doesn't show up on Android.

[image: Android']

How can I solve this problem?

> The Text File Location: Assets/Resources/Magnelli_0.27.txt

Comment: Where is the text supposed to show up?  Also, you have a lot to clean up here. 1) You don't do anything with `reader` other than dispose it and close it. 2) When you assign `str`, you're setting it to `asset.ToString()` instead of `asset.text`. 3) `arrZ = new double[length];` and `arrCV = new double[length];` can happen in the end of `Start()` instead of every frame in `Update()`. 4) You don't need `path` and the `StreamReader` that uses it since you're already using `Resouces.Load()`. 5) The way you're indexing `sprite[]` on lines 60 & 61 means you'll only ever use the first two values.

Comment: 6) You're doing `GetComponent<Text>().text =` in a loop so every time that happens, it will overwrite the text you previously set it to.

Comment: @GuntherFox Thanks a lot! I edited my code :) overwriting the text is what I want. It works well on Unity Game View, but It doesn't work on Android (T_T)

Comment: @GuntherFox It works on Android!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thanks a million!!!!!!!!! wow!!!!!!! I really really appreciate it!!!!!!!!

Comment: No problem! Glad it worked out for ya :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem!! I followed @Gunther Fox 's comment, and it was working on Android!

[image: answer]

```
1. private TextAsset asset;
2. private string str;
3. private string[] names;
4. private Vector3 ViewPosition;
5. private double ViewZPosition;
6. private int length;
7. private double[] arrZ;
8. private double[] arrCV; 
9. 
10. // Use this for initialization
11. void Start () {
12.     Screen.sleepTimeout = SleepTimeout.NeverSleep;
13. 
14.     asset = Resources.Load ("Magnelli_0.27")as TextAsset;
15. 
16.     str = asset.text;
17.     names = str.Split('\n');
18.     length = names.Length;
19. 
20.     arrZ = new double[length];
21.     arrCV = new double[length];
22. 
23. }
24. 
25. // Update is called once per frame
26. void Update () {
27. 
28.     ViewPosition = GameObject.FindWithTag("MainCamera").transform.position;
29.     ViewZPosition = ViewPosition.z;
30. 
31.     TextReader txtreader = new StringReader (asset.text);
32.     StringReader streader = new StringReader (asset.text);
33. 
34.     string txt = "";
35. 
36.     for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
37. 
38.         txt = streader.ReadLine();
39.         string[] sprite = txt.Split (' ');
40. 
41.         arrZ[i] = Convert.ToDouble(sprite[0]);
42.         arrCV[i] = Convert.ToDouble(sprite[1]);
43.     }
44.     for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
45.         
46.         if ((arrZ[i])*100-0.2 < ViewZPosition & (arrZ[i])*100+0.2 > ViewZPosition)
47.         {
48. 
49.             GetComponent<Text>().text = "redshift z : " + ViewZPosition*0.01 + "\nComoving Volume : " + arrCV[i] + " Gpc³";
50.         }
51.     }
52. }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please put file Magnelli_0.27 as TextAsset into Resouce folder and reader line per line with StringReader. I think when u build for another OS path valuable will wrong and then it not show up text.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It didn't work (T. T)

StringReader streader = new StringReader (asset.text);